# How do I redirect non-existant subdirectory in my index.php file, keeping the URL

Tags: php, web

I want to basically be able to goto, for example: www.example.com/my/folder/
where the subdirectories /my/folder/ don't exist, and have it redirect to index.php?path=/my/folder, while still keeping the original URL.

I hope this makes sense. I basically have no idea where to start with this. I'm guessing it's something with .htaccess, or http.conf or something, but I have no clue.

I basically want some direction on where to figure out how to do this, or some suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always liked borrowing from the Wordpress `.htaccess` file myself

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This little bit of code will rewrite anything that is not a file and send it to your index.php file. You can then parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for anything you need from the URL itself.

Comment: Thanks! Just had to remove the <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> and </IfModule> and it worked perfect!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what web server you're running.  If you're running Apache, then yes, it's in the [`.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) file or the [`VirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) file.  In addition, [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html) will need to be enabled on your Apache server for this to work.

```
sudo a2enmod mod_rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Other web servers will have it in different locations and require different commands.