# How to parse data from url. (pretty urls)

Tags: php, url

So using `$_GET[]`your url looks like

```
yourdomain.com/index.php?page=home | lets say this loads home
```

I want it to be

```
yourdomain.com/home
```

I don't want to have many folders with a bunch of index.php's either, I want to run everything through the index.

how would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you made **any** research?

Comment: @TimO'Connell This is one of the oldest and most repeatedly solved problems in the entirety of PHP. There are thousands of duplicates on Stack Overflow alone. Read up on ModRewrite.

Comment: @meagar I guess I am just not typing in the right thing on google.  What string do you search?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341598/how-do-i-redirect-non-existant-subdirectory-in-my-index-php-file-keeping-the-ur/20341662 also answers this

Comment: You're looking for rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

mysite.com?var1=20&var2=this_is_a_new_article

Of course, in your index.php file you can simply take the values using

$var1 = $_GET['var1'];
$var2 = $_GET['var2'];